# How to get data Horizontally from table Compliance Data Based on Part Id and Compliance Type Id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I work on SQL Server 2014 I need to get data from compliance data table horizontally.

- based on part id and compliance type Id 1,2,11
- every part id will have one row per 3 compliance type
- every row per part will have 3 compliance type id 1,2,11
- if part not have 3 compliance then it will take Null on empty compliance Type
- as part id 749120,4620

How to do that please?

Sample data as below

```
create table #ComplianceData 
(
    PartId int,
    ComplianceTypeID int,
    CompStatus nvarchar(30),
    VersionOrder int,
    ComplianceType nvarchar(30)
)

insert into # ComplianceData (PartId, ComplianceTypeID, CompStatus, VersionOrder, ComplianceType)
values (5090, 1, 'Compliant', 3, 'Rohs'),
       (5090, 1, 'NotCompliant', 40, 'Rohs'),
       (5090, 2, 'Compliant', 25, 'Reach'),
       (5090, 11, 'NotCompliant', 1, 'TSKA'),
       (2306, 1, 'Compliant', 3, 'Rohs'),
       (2306, 2, 'NotCompliant', 25, 'Reach'),
       (2306, 11, 'Compliant', 1, 'TSKA'),
       (4620, 1, 'NotCompliant', 3, 'Rohs'),
       (4620, 2, 'Compliant', 25, 'Reach'),
       (749120, 2, 'Compliant', 25, 'Reach')
```

Result required as

[image: Display Data Horizontally Based On Part Id]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: ok i will not do again

Comment: Please edit this question.

Comment: so what i will edit on mmy question

Comment: how you will now result i need if i remove image

Comment: Formatted text...

Comment: Keep in mind we want a [mre] with emphasis in minimal, i.e. only show the rows and columns necessary to demonstrate the issue you have, don't include your entire data.

Comment: i remove some data

Comment: to make it as small production sample

Comment: Still got an unreadable image and no attempt.

Comment: you should create temp table with your sent picture structure and then add data to table with SQL Server Cursors.

Comment: Using cursors should be a last resort and is very rarely necessary.

Comment: thank you for reply can you show me how to do it with cursor please

Comment: can you please show me how to do it by cursor

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to UNPIVOT your data, and then PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select PartId
              ,B.*
         From #ComplianceData A
         Cross Apply ( values ( concat(ComplianceType,'ComplianceTypeID'),left(ComplianceTypeID,50))
                             ,( concat(ComplianceType,'CompStatus'),CompStatus)
                             ,( concat(ComplianceType,'VersionOrder'),left(VersionOrder,50))
                     ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in (   [RohsComplianceTypeID],
                                    [RohsCompStatus],
                                    [RohsVersionOrder],
                                    [ReachComplianceTypeID],
                                    [ReachCompStatus],
                                    [ReachVersionOrder],
                                    [TSKAComplianceTypeID],
                                    [TSKACompStatus],
                                    [TSKAVersionOrder]
                                ) 
       ) src
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By`

```
select  PartId,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Rohs', ComplianceTypeID, NULL)) as RohsComplianceTypeID,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Rohs', CompStatus, NULL)) as RohsCompStatus,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Rohs', VersionOrder, NULL)) as RohsVersionOrder,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Rohs', ComplianceType, NULL)) as RohsComplianceType,
        
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Reach', ComplianceTypeID, NULL)) as ReachComplianceTypeID,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Reach', CompStatus, NULL)) as ReachCompStatus,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Reach', VersionOrder, NULL)) as ReachVersionOrder,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'Reach', ComplianceType, NULL)) as ReachComplianceType,
        
        
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'TSKA', ComplianceTypeID, NULL)) as TSKAComplianceTypeID,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'TSKA', CompStatus, NULL)) as TSKACompStatus,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'TSKA', VersionOrder, NULL)) as TSKAVersionOrder,
        max(IIF(ComplianceType = 'TSKA', ComplianceType, NULL)) as TSKAComplianceType
               
from #ComplianceData 
group by PartId
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3f20aea92e442bcc0cfd6fb8c73b04fd)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicates by PartId and ComplianceTypeID (and get record with the largest VersionOrder), group records by ComplianceType, and in each group transpose columns to rows and add ComplianceType to each Item, and then concatenate all records and transpose rows to columns. It is really a hassle to express the algorithm in SQL. No matter you use Cross Apply ( values … and perform a transposition, or use group by, the SQL statement will be lengthy and can only apply the current scenario. An alternative is to export data out of database and handle it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate much simpler code. It does the task with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MSSQL.query("select * from ComplianceData order by 2,1,4 desc") |
| 2 | =A1.group@o1(#1,#2).group@o(#5).(~.pivot@r(PartId;Item,Value)).run(type=~.select@1(Item=="ComplianceType").Value, ~.(Item=type/Item)).conj().pivot(PartId;Item,Value) |